# Foreground Segmentation using Matlab

Tags: matlab, video, segmentation-fault, matlab-cvst

Anyone has idea of segment foreground in a video using Matlab ? I've tried vision.ForegroundDetector which uses Gaussian Mixture Model.However, it didn't perform well in my 'bending' video from Weizmann. (http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SpaceTimeActions.html)

Appreciate a lot if anyone could suggest me some other methods / built-in functions

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what specifically did not work?  Have you tried adjusting parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If the background is static you can try to write algorithm that will assign a pair of numbers for {bg,fg} for every pixel in every frame.

The score will be accumulate through some rules. for example:

1) For some pixel, if it similar to its neighbor then its score will come close to its neighbor score.

2) For some pixel, if it similar to itself in most of frames then its bg score will rise.

3) For some pixel, if it different from itself in the other most of frames then its fg score will rise.

You can assign different accumulator weight to each rule.